# How to select data with specific values/rows in search textbox?

Tags: vb.net, select, oledbcommand

Here's my table:

| EmployeeNo | User | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 108 | Jeff | Mouse |
| 109 | Ven | Keyboard |
| 110 | Jeff | Monitor |

Here's my code in Search TextBox:

```
Dim query As string = "Select [EmployeeNo], [User], [Item] 
Where [EmployeeNo] Like '%" & txtSearchbox.Text & "%' Or 
[User] Like '%" & txtSearchbox.Text & "%' Or [Item] Like '%" 
& txtSearchbox.Text & "%'
Using con as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("datasourceofdatabase")
    Using cmd as oledbcommand = new oledbcommand(query1, con)
        Using da as oledbdataadapter = new oledbdataadapter(cmd)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
         Using dt1 as new datatable() 
            da.Fill(dt1)
            If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Datagridview1.Datasource = dt1
            Else
                MsgBox("No Data Found", vbError) 
            End If
          End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Note: This is live search data with textbox which means it will filter live in my datagridview.

Now, while I search on textbox, I want to select all data with Jeff only.

What command would I use? Shall I add this right after inside a query in my txtSearchBox?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Desktop (what Platform), Web? Have you already loaded your data? What selector do you have to specify a `User`? As of now, your input TextBox is a multi-purpose selector. Maybe add one or more input tools that allow to specify multiple options instead a single, generic, input. You can also use auto-complete TextBoxes (if the Platform allows it), or pre-filled ComboBoxes (if available) with an `All` / `Any` option at index 0. -- Is `[EmployeeNo]` actually a string type (in your database)?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your are using `_dataTable1` to get your table, and your filter name is `Filter1`

you can do as follow:

```
Private Sub txtSearchbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearchbox.TextChanged

Dim Filter1 As String
Filter1 = "EmployeeNo LIKE '%" & txtSearchbox.Text & "%' OR " & _
          "User LIKE '%" & txtSearchbox.Text & "%' OR " & _
          "Item LIKE '%" & txtSearchbox.Text & "%'"

    ' Sort bonus ;)
    Dim Sort1 As String = " User  ASC"

    _dataTable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = Filter1
    _dataTable1.DefaultView.Sort = Sort1    

    'Bind your DataGridView1 to your _dataTable1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = _dataTable1
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Supposing that previously you declared your `_dataTable1` public and already loaded the data inside with your query

```
Public _dataTable1 As New DataTable()

Public Sub New()

' Do you query here
Dim query As string = "Select [EmployeeNo], [User], [Item] "
Using con as oledbconnection = new oledbconnection("datasourceofdatabase")
....
....
If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                _dataTable1 = dt1
....
....
End Sub
```

I suggest you to take a look to the following :  [VB.NET DataGridView binding - Sql Server](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_binding.htm)  there is simple example that work very well and easy to understand. Not only for DataGridView but for all VB.net.

Comment: @KarrieGorSan , Mark it as accepted answer if it does answer to your question !

Comment: what's this code ? better remove it from comments, and add EDIT: in your post and put those lines ...

Comment: I'm done editing my code. Btw your code does not work to me, my datagridview still filtering all of data instead of Jeff only.

Comment: And also, there will be lot of users that will login so, just imagine, there is a login form, then if Jeff login, that datagridview in another form will show Jeff user only and also when I search on textbox as well.

Comment: My only problem is when I search on textbox, my datagridview was still showing all data and users.

Comment: Still not working. It says missing operand after [EmployeeNo] operator. Is that sort a query? And where should I place those dt1.defaultview.rowfilter? And btw I have another method for displaying table of my datagridview. I willl just call that in Form Load.